# iphone app new update popup

Tags: iphone

I've seen apps the shows a dialog box when a new version of the app is available.

How does it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: I want it to show up when the user opens the new version of the app for the first time. is that possible with push notifications?

Comment: I do not really understand, your questions seem contradictory.
If you want to be able to send messages to users when a new version is available then use push notifications, if you want to display something the first time a user opens your app then just store some thing unique to that version of the app using NSUserDefaults and check against it when you app launches.